# How to access id of <asp:Hidden> control from ascx page to cs page

Tags: asp.net, c#

This is my *ascx* Code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Demo.ascx.cs"
            Inherits="Demo" %>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" Value="" />
```

And the *aspx*:

```
<%@ Register TagName="Hidden" TagPrefix="CRS" Src="~/Demo.ascx" %>

<div>
   <CRS:Hidden ID="hid" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Now How to access Hidden variable ID From ascx page to this cs page backend

Comment: by ID like `hid.GetType().Name`

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the actual ID? or the Value within the hidden field?

You can access the value using the `FindControl` method

```
HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)this.hid.FindControl("hidden");
string theValue = hf.Value;
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.

Alternatively, you can declare some public properties in the UserControl in which you can access directly

In the ascx code:

```
public string theValue { get; set; }
```

In the aspx code:

```
string theValue = this.hid.theValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the `HiddenField` inside the `UserControl` from the asp.net web page you will need to wire up something called a `Public Property`.

This code should be added to the `UserControl` ascx.cs code behind:

```
public string Value
{
    get { return hidden.Value; }
    set { hidden.Value = value; }
}
```

You could then write code like this in your asp.net page:

```
string SomeHiddenValue = hid.Value;
hid.Value = "Its a secret!";
```

Note: I haven't compiled this so I am not sure if the public property name of `Value` will compile. I am also not sure if the second value in `set { hidden.Value = value; }` needs capitalising. Try changing these two values if you encounter problems.